# PyCURL couldn't resolve "cdrom:sr0" during CentOS 6.2 kickstart installation

Tags: centos, installation, kickstart

I'm trying to install CentOS 6.2 by kickstart, and I'm using the stock minimal ISO and the auto-generated anaconda-ks.cfg. After the installation finished partition the hard drive, I get an error message saying "Unable to read package metadata", and the /tmp/anaconda.log has the following line:

```
ERROR: Error downloading treeinfo file: [Error 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'cdrom:sr0'"
```

My kickstart file:

```
# Kickstart file automatically generated by anaconda.

#version=DEVEL
install
cdrom
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard us
network --onboot no --device eth0 --noipv4 --noipv6
firewall --service=ssh
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
selinux --enforcing
timezone --utc America/New_York
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda --append=" rhgb crashkernel=auto quiet"
# The following is the partition information you requested
# Note that any partitions you deleted are not expressed
# here so unless you clear all partitions first, this is
# not guaranteed to work
clearpart --all --drives=sda
part /boot --fstype=ext4 --size=500
part pv.008002 --grow --size=1
volgroup VolGroup --pesize=4096 pv.008002
logvol / --fstype=ext4 --name=lv_root --vgname=VolGroup --grow --size=1024 --maxsize=51200
logvol swap --name=lv_swap --vgname=VolGroup --grow --size=512 --maxsize=1024


repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=cdrom:sr0 --cost=100

%packages --nobase
@core
%end
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue myself, the solution is changing the `repo` line from

```
repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=cdrom:sr0 --cost=100
```

to

```
repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=file:///mnt/source --cost=100
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the same problem (in CentOS 6.5) completly removing  the `repo`
line from kickstart file.